# Jquery dependent dropdown only works with excessive variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have very basic JS skills, so please excuse me if I'm trying to fix something what doesn't need fixing.

I use select2 dropdown. When user selects any option, it gets posted to remote file, which returns possible options (in JSON format) to be displayed in 2nd (dependent) dropdown.

1st select looks following:

```
<select name="restaurant_id" id="restaurant_id">my_options_go_here</select>
```

2nd (dependent) select looks:

```
<select name="division_ids_array[]" id="division_ids_array" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

And here's JS code:

```
  $(function () {
  function ajax_post_data_get_divisions(parameters) {
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "ajax.php",
      cache: false,
      data: parameters,
      success: function(data) {
        var dropdown_options=$('#division_ids_array');
            dropdown_options.empty();
        var dropdown_options="";
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                dropdown_options+='<option value="'+val.division_id+'" '+val.selected+'>'+val.division_name+'</option>';
            });
        $(dropdown_options).appendTo("#division_ids_array");
      }
    });
  }

  $('#restaurant_id').on("change", function(e) {
  parameters=$("#my_form_id").serialize();
  ajax_post_data_get_divisions(parameters);
  });
});
```

Everything works fine, but I somehow believe these lines are excessive:

```
var dropdown_options=$('#division_ids_array');
            dropdown_options.empty();
        var dropdown_options="";
```

Please excuse my ignorance, but it looks variable `dropdown_options` gets created first, then it gets set to empty, and then the same variable is created again?

Unfortunately, if I remove at least one line, nothing works. For example, if I try to simply code to:

```
var dropdown_options=$('#division_ids_array');
dropdown_options.empty();
```

dependent dropdown remains empty. Is it an error in my code?

Comment: keep only `var dropdown_options="";` as string is getting concatenated in to it in `.each`

Comment: Tried that too, didn't work the way I expected. Works great for 1st selection, but when user re-selects any option from 1st dropdown, all the previous options in 2nd (dependent) dropdown remain (while they shouldn't)

Comment: oh! then you should make it as `$('#division_ids_array').empty();var dropdown_options="";`

Comment: You're using the same variable name for different things. First it's a jQuery object that you empty, then you redeclare the same variable as an empty string.

Comment: Prashant Shirke - thank you, this one works fine.